# Retrieve multiple hostnames from one ipaddress in DNS

Tags: c#, dns, a-records

I'm having difficulty to find a solution, to find multiple hostnames (A-Records) in our DNS, that have the same IP-address. Because I Have multiple docker containers running on a single host, that each need an A-Record with the Host's ip-address to be accessible from outside my host-server. When I retrieve this list, I can check if there are any orphaned a-reords that do not have a docker container.

I have this code that only retrieves a single ip-address. Im using the DNSClient-library but if the DNS library supports a solution that would be appreciated.

```
var DnsAddress = "10.0.4.25"

var client = new LookupClient(DnsAddress);
var result = client.Query("10.0.4.238", QueryType.A);

foreach (var aRecord in result.Answers.ARecords())
{
    Console.WriteLine(aRecord);
}
```

Comment: It seems to me that you need PTR record, not A. Because you getting names from IP.

Comment: The result might have the information you need in the Additionals records. Probably PTR records as @Max mentioned.